# TFS 2010 Build: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.SyncWorkspace

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, tfsbuild

If I call (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.SyncWorkspace), it seems to get all the folders and files from the workspace. Can I specify the only selected folder to be downloaded?

Say, Workspace is mapped to RootDir_A.

RootDir_A
   |---- SubDir_A
   |---- SubDir_B
   |---- SubDir_C
   |---- SubDir_D
   '---- SubDir_E

If I only want to get SubDir_B and SubDir_C from the Workspace. What do I need to specify?

Answer (score 1):

You need to scope down your working folder mappings of your build definition to just the sub folders you want to sync and build. Open your build definition in Visual Studio to edit, and go to the working folder mappings tab to remove or cloak the ones you do not want.

Comment: so apparently, that is the only way?